# How to change riak storage backend property using Scala/Java code

Tags: riak, riak-search, nosql

Is there any way to override riak default property using Scala/Java code?

```
{riak_kv, [
...,
{storage_backend, riak_kv_memory_backend},
...
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Riak 1.x changing storage backends can only be performed by changing the configuration and restarting the server. You could read the configuration using Parboiled, Antlr, JavaCC, or whatever parser you are familiar with, then write it back out and restart the server.